# How to install mysql 8.0 client on Debian Buster?

Tags: mysql, debian

This is how I would install a central Mysql 8.0 database on Debian 10.

```
MYSQL_8_file="mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb"
apt install gnupg -y
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/${MYSQL_8_file}
dpkg -i ${MYSQL_8_file}
apt update
apt install -y mysql-server
```

So far so good. But I also another Debian 10 instance that doesn't need a mysql server, but only a client to connect to the central mysql 8.0 server.

But there is no mysql 8 compatible client available.

There is only `apt install default-mysql-client`, which lacks:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so`

Is there a way to just install mysql8-client on Debian buster without having to install the whole mysql server? (Because the instances don't have so much memory to begin with)

Answer (score 1):

I missed the wood for the trees.

The selection in the `dpkg -i ${MYSQL_8_file}` screen confused me first that the entire mysql server 8.0 will be installed. But it only selects the available packages.

Hence all I had to do was `apt install -y mysql-client` instead of `apt install -y mysql-server`.